Not all Hindi matches are being returned when using custom analyzer
I am working on a FastAPI project that uses OpenSearch with a custom index to support both Hindi and English text. I created a custom analyzer for Hindi, but I am encountering an issue where search results seem incomplete.
Index Creation:
I created an index with a custom analyzer for the chapter_title field like this:
def create_index():
    """Create an OpenSearch index with language-specific analyzers for Hindi and English."""
    if not opensearch_client.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
        opensearch_client.indices.create(
            INDEX_NAME,
            body={
                "settings": {
                    "analysis": {
                        "analyzer": {
                            "custom_chapter_title_analyzer": {
                                "type": "custom",
                                "tokenizer": "standard",
                                "filter": [
                                    "hindi_normalization",
                                    "indic_normalization",
                                ],
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "mappings": {
                    "properties": {
                        "book_title": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "english"},
                        "chapter_title": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "custom_chapter_title_analyzer",
                        },
                    }
                },
            },
        )

Search Implementation:
For searching, I am using a multi_match query on both book_title and chapter_title fields:
@app.get("/search/")
def search_books(q: str):
    
    print('\nSearch query:')
    print(q)

    query = {
        'size': 5,
        "query": {
            "multi_match": {
                "query": q,
                "fields": ["book_title", "chapter_title"]
            }
        }
    }
    response = opensearch_client.search_book(query)
    print('\nSearch results:')
    print(response)
    return response

Issue:
When searching for the term "संगठन", I only get results for one of the following chapter_title values:

संगठनः अनूठा और क्रांतिकारी
संगठन और धर्म

I only get a match for "संगठन और धर्म" but not for "संगठनः अनूठा और क्रांतिकारी".
I suspect this might be due to the : character (the symbol "ः") being treated differently during tokenization, but I’m unsure how to resolve this.
Like wise:
In search when i have: केंद्रः
I get this result as first result:

ध्यान-केंद्रः
जीवन का गुह्यतम केंद्रः मृत्यु

But when i have only the search query as: केंद्र
I didn't get above result, i get only matching value of केंद्र
Question:
How can I adjust my custom analyzer to ensure that search queries return all results containing the Hindi term "संगठन", regardless of the presence of punctuation or other special characters like "ः"?
Is this even possible?
Edit:
I used _analyze API call to understand how the strings are tokenized and indexed.
And seems like the : is the part of the text string that is being tokenized.
This endpoint returns http://localhost:9200/books/_analyze:
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "संगठनः",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "अनुठा",
            "start_offset": 7,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "ओर",
            "start_offset": 13,
            "end_offset": 15,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "करांतिकारि",
            "start_offset": 16,
            "end_offset": 27,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}


I feel like you are close to find what you are looking for. Just use the _analyze API call to understand how the strings are tokenized and indexed.
https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/analyze-apis/#derive-the-analyzer-from-an-index-field

@MusabDogan I did what you suggested, should i remove those character from the index input? Or is there any better approach in OpenSearch? if There is built in method then it would be useful because there could be numerous such strings...

Hope you liked the _analyze API call.
There is no out-of-box solution for what you are asking. Yes, you can drop the all the characters except Hindi Alphabet with Logstash or an ingest pipeline. You should define it manually.
